# youtube embed causes continuos get_screen_availability requests in net panel

Tags: javascript, youtube

reproduce:

1. go to http://jsbin.com/bules/1/
2. open console
3. go to net panel
4. see a lot of requests almost every 3seconds from youtube

With open console in chrome it causes memory leak after an hour or so.

Can someone explain why is that happening and why is this call so frequent?

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing this same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by a polling from the player. It checks whether I have my paired smartTV is turned on or not. So it can hide/show the remote-screen button on player.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 youtube iframe do pulling every ~10 seconds, I guess they are doing it with some sort of socket with Flash and couldn't find a more reliable way to do it with HTML5 (eg: WebSockets are not implemented everywhere).

So this is just part of the **normal YouTube HTML5 iframe behavior**. Hopefully it will get fixed and replaced by a better system one day.

[image: get_screen_availability polling]

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when googling to solve the problem. I have the same problem (still, YT haven't solved in a better way). I had requests every ~5 sec. The client (FF) was sending the requests no matter if I had a youtube page up or not.

I found this is solution:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3230451?hl=en
I couldn't manage to turn it off with the instructions for `On computer`, I had to do it from the TV. And the restart FF to get rid of it.